# Error While Adding Wildcard subdomain entry in vercel "The specified value "*.custom-subdomain.vercel.app/" is not a fully qualified domain name"

Tags: reactjs, subdomain, hosting, vercel, wildcard-subdomain

I am working on feature where i have to create two routes using reactjs.
first route: simple domain name: custom-subdomain.vercel.app/ <= responsible to show home page.
second route: sub domain route, different for each user: abc.custom-subdomain.vercel.app/  <= responsible to show profile of abc user.
I have developed the code and it working just fin with my localhost. But when i a hosting, it is not working well.

I am hosting this project using vercel and when i am adding wildcard subdomain entry in the vercel, it is showing error.

[image]

Github repo link: https://github.com/shubham-sapkal/custom-subdomain
Hosted Link: https://custom-subdomain.vercel.app/

Thanks you in advanced for your help.

I have tried all options that i got on the internet but not worked well. I just want one solution that is free of cost cause hosting on vercel is totally free. Just i don't know where hosting with subdomain is free or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.